# put empty string instead of null in JSON string

Tags: c#, json

I want to put an empty string in my JSON file rather than null value. Is it possible to do quickly with any C# utility or any other way

```
{
   "typeOfPerson":"",
   "personDetails":{
      "dateOfBirth":"12/20/2019"
   }
}
```

I have below C# code to get the above JSON:

public class person
    {

```
    public string typeOfPerson { get; set; }
    public List<PersonDetails> personDetails { get; set; } = new List<PersonDetails>();

}

I have below C# code to get above JSON



public void test()
{
    Person person = new Person();
    person.personDetails = new PersonDetails() { dateOfBirth = "12/20/2019" };

    string JSONresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);
    string jsonFormatted = JValue.Parse(JSONresult).ToString(Formatting.Indented);
}
```

above class creates this JSON:

```
{
   "typeOfPerson":null,
   "personDetails":{
      "dateOfBirth":"12/20/2019"
   }
}
```

This creates the JSON with null value in typeofperson. Is it possible to get empty string instead of null value? I can always initialize typeofperson="", but I have a huge JSON file and it has lot of empty strings . Any utility that can put ""  instead of null in JSONREsult string.

any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Easy `public string typeOfPerson { get; set; } = string.Empty`

Comment: Like, I mentioned before, I can initialize each and property to empty string, but that will take lot of time. Is it quicker way to replace the entire JSON string null values to ""

Answer (score -1):

public class person {

```
public string typeOfPerson { get; set; } = "";
public List<PersonDetails> personDetails { get; set; } = new List<PersonDetails>();
```

}

you can try it like this.